# JavaScript: how pass edge cases with ternary conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, if-statement

How I can achieve here with some edge cases that might happen .

//Edge cases
If `mediaType` is `undefined` it should return `undefined` or `infinity` and if `mediaType` is `xs` it should return `xs` with current implementation.

//code current implementation

```
function getCurrentBreakpoint(mediaType) {
  const mediaTypes = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "infinity"];
  return mediaTypes[mediaTypes.indexOf(mediaType) - 1];
}
```

Any help here.

Comment: @AakashChauhan it will be nything from `xs` to `infinity`

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution:**

```
      function getCurrentBreakpoint(mediaType) {
          const mediaTypes = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "infinity"];
          return mediaType=="xs"?"xs":mediaTypes[mediaTypes.indexOf(mediaType) - 1]?mediaTypes[mediaTypes.indexOf(mediaType) - 1]:"infinity";
       }
```

Comment: Its my bad. I was wrongly interpreted this question. I have edited my answer please check again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#find`:

```js
function getCurrentBreakpoint(mediaType) {
  const mediaTypes = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "infinity"];
  return mediaTypes.find(mt => mt === mediaType);
}

console.log(getCurrentBreakpoint('xs'));
console.log(getCurrentBreakpoint('foo'));
console.log(getCurrentBreakpoint());
```

And if you really want to use a ternary operator, you can use this instead.

```
return mediaTypes.includes(mediaType) ? mediaType : undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getCurrentBreakpoint(mediaType) {
    const mediaTypes = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "infinity"];

    const index = mediaTypes.indexOf(mediaType);

    if(index !== -1){
        return mediaTypes[index];
    }

    return "infinity";
}
```

OR

```
    function getCurrentBreakpoint(mediaType) {
        const mediaTypes = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "infinity"];

        return mediaTypes.find(ele => ele === mediaType) || "infinity";
    }
```

Comment: @TanmoySarkar can I know the scenario?

Comment: Current code will not return previous index value of mediaType.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if mediaType is undefined by simply doing

```
if (!mediaType) {
/* ... */
}
```

It's unclear the context in which you are calling the function but if you want to return undefined (which I don't think is that much of a good practice) you could just do:

```
if (!mediaType) {
    return mediaType
}
```

EDIT: The user changed post and title to be used with a ternary.

then it would be

```
return !mediaType ? mediaType : /* whatever */
```

If it was the other way and you wanted it to be always defined you could use a binary conditional:

```
return mediaType && /* whatever */
```

Comment: @jenero it should be using ternary operator only.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar - why? you stated in your question you want to use "if/else"

Comment: My bad really . I have to use it as simple as it is as because i tried this with `switch` and `if-else` condition before.

Comment: well witha  ternary operator it is   return !mediaType ? mediaType : mediaTypes[mediaTypes.indexOf(mediaType) - 1];

Comment: It breaks for `xs` type .

Comment: Well then you can check (mediaType !== 0 && !mediaType)

Comment: @TanmoySarkar why are you using the final -1? mediaTypes.indexOf('xs') -1 is -1, then you are trying to access the mediaTypes[-1] that will return undefined, I don't think that is what you want

Comment: Yes that is what current implementation. but to edge our different cases i want to change my latest with some new where both `xs` and `undefined` can be handled.